# Force knitr highlighting for piped functions

Tags: r, knitr, magrittr

Here's an .Rnw MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, eval=FALSE)
@
\begin{document}
Function highlighted:
<<c1>>=
print(iris)
@
Function highlighted if parameter is present:
<<c2>>=
library(magrittr)
iris %>%
  print(someparam = 42)
@
No highlighting:
<<c3>>=
iris %>%
  print
@
\end{document}
```

It renders like so: 
[image]

How can I force syntax highlighting for the last `print` function?

Comment: @rawr As a last resort, yes. But I'd like to omit that redundancy if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suitable solution I found so far is to modify the latex source produced by `knitr`. Namely, changing `\hlstd(print)` (standard highlighting) to `\hlkwd(print)` (function highlighting + bold by default) manually should do the job.